# MediaTek MT7922 wifi6e on 23.04 kenel 6.4

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, asus, mediatek

I am still puzzled why the MediaTek MT7922 from my Asus ROG-B650A motherboard can't find my 6ghz wifi signal. I already update the kernel from 6.2->6.4 on a fresh Ubuntu 23.04. But still no luck to find the 6Ghz signal. It works totally fine with my dual-booted windows 11.

One issue maybe that it use the mt7921e drivers still? Here's the output from

```
inxi -N
```

```
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I225-V driver: igc
  Device-2: MEDIATEK MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
    driver: mt7921e
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzVEo.png)

So anyone get any suggestions how to solve this problems? I think kernel 6.4 added support for MediaTek MT7922. Thanks a lot!